# Get all users and roles in BIM 360 data management API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I am trying unsuccessfully to get all the users of a project and roles assigned to users. The errorCode AUTH-010 is not found on the Autodesk error  handling page.

Scope - data:read
Using 3-legged Auth to this endpoint https://developer.api.autodesk.com/bim360/admin/v1/projects/:projectId/users
with an access token that works for most other requests, get hubs, get project, get permissions by folder. The request return an error of the token does have privilege for the request. I am an account admin on the hub.

the error is

```
{
    "developerMessage": "Token does not have the privilege for this request.",
    "moreInfo": "https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/error_handling/",
    "errorCode": "AUTH-010"
}
```

Is it possible to get users and user roles for a BIM 360 project?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This endpoint requires the `account:read` scope, please ensure you have included it when getting the access tokens via the [Authentication (OAuth) API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/developers_guide/overview/).

ref: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/admin-v1-projects-projectId-users-GET/